# Continuum limit for discrete differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, continuum-mechanics, discrete

I have a very simple first-order differential equation (coming from a quantum problem of hopping on a lattice)
$$ i\dot\psi_m = a_{m-1}\psi_{m-1}+a_m\psi_{m+1},\quad m\in[1,...,N]. $$
I would like to pass to some sort of continuum limit as $N\to\infty$, which presumably involves spatial derivatives up to second order. However, I'm doubtful if this problem can be solved for general $a_i$, at least I can't see how.

My approach would have been to write $\psi_{m+1}=\psi_m+\Delta x\psi_m'+\cdots$ (similar for $a$) and look at the leading order term of the right hand side. However, I get
$$ i\dot\psi = 2 a \psi-2\Delta x a'\psi+(\Delta x)^2[a\psi''+a'\psi'/2+a''\psi]i +\mathcal O(\Delta x^3). $$
(Here, $a(x_m)$ and $\psi=\psi(x_m)$, but I've suppressed the argument.)
I'm not even sure if that expansion is correct, but anyway I have no idea how to deal with the fact that there are several different orders on the RHS. The present equation seems to suggest that $i\dot\psi=2a\psi$ in the continuum limit, but that would imply no dynamics at all, which is not what I would expect when looking at the differential version.

In case anyone wonders, boundary conditions are open, i.e., $i\dot\psi_1=a_1\psi_2$ and similarly for $i\dot\psi_N$.

### Edit

#### form of $a_m$

A comment asked whether $a_m$ has a continuum limit. In the case I'm studying $a_m=m(N-m+1)$ (related to a spin), and I realize there could be two different continuum limits. One is keeping $m\in\mathbb I$ (integers), and sending $N$ to infinity, and the other is to introduce a length $\Delta x$ which goes to zero while keeping $N \Delta x=L$ constant. This gives $a(x)=x(L-x)$.

I probably want the latter, but I'm also curious what the difference is.

#### Keeping the first term

If I only keep the first term, the suggested solution (keeping the first term) therefore is
$$i\dot\psi(x) = 2x(L-x)\psi(x). $$
I'm unhappy with this solution, because it means nothing moves, contrary to what happens in the discrete case.

#### Edit 2: Alternative form of $a_m$

@Wolphram jonny suggested that $a_m$ as defined above has no appropriate continuum limit. I think an alternative version could read
$$ a_m = m(N_0n-m+1)/n^2,\quad m\in[1,\dots,nN_0], $$
where the continuum limit I am interested in corresponds to $n\to\infty$. $n=1$ is the case we start with and the procedure can be thought of as subdividing each step $n$ times. As far as I can tell this yields the continuum form of $a(x)$ as stated above, but I still don't understand where the dynamics have gone.

Comment: how do $a_m$ and $\psi _m$ behave? do their magnitude get close to each other as N grows? if they do just keep the first term of your series, if not it is not continuumizable

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That's a very good question. I have $a_m=m(N-m+1)$, so when dividing everything by $N^2$, yes. That said, actually, I think taking $a(x)=x(L-x+1)$ for some finite length would give a different result, and I think be more appropriate?

Comment: I could not follow how you got a=x(L-x), but by noticing that $a_{m+1}-a_m=N-2m$ I do not think you can write a as a continuous function

Comment: Well, one way of taking a continuum limit would be to introduce a spacing $\Delta x$, such that $a_m\to a(m\Delta x)=\Delta x^2 m(N-m+1)=x(L-x)$, with $x=m\Delta x$ and $L=N\Delta x$. not sure if this makes sense though.

Comment: I do not think the last comment makes sense. For instance, how do you justify the $\Delta x ^2$ at the front? there is no $\Delta m$ that would be the equivalent to $\Delta x$

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What about the explanation I added in edit 2?